# Creating task using Rally rest API

Tags: c#, rally

When creating task using Rally's rest API (C#), it is now creating more than one more task to a single call of create task in the code. This has been working the last few months. This behavior is more recent, happening over the last week or so.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code?  I haven't heard any other reports of this sort of behavior, so I'd be curious to see how you're creating tasks...

Answer (score 0):

We have had some periodic issues with the .NET toolkit and some crazy retry logic that was built-in for the Excel add-in but really isn't a great feature for most users.

Does your RallyRestApi constructor take a maxRetries parameter?  What happens if you try setting that to 0 or 1?

Here's the constructor signature: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/blob/master/Rally.RestApi/RallyRestApi.cs#L206

So you should be able to just pass a value of 0 or 1 to the constructor for that maxRetries parameter.

Comment: I'm using the  version 3.2.1.0 of rally rest API. No, I haven't used the max retries option. What is the option, can you please give an example? - Thanks

Comment: Updated answer above ^^  I am also going to file a github issue to investigate...  https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/issues/38

Comment: Yes, actually I have maxretries set to 3. Here is the signature that I currently have  public RallyRestApi(ApiAuthManager authManger = null, string webServiceVersion = "v2.0", int maxRetries = 3, TraceFieldEnum traceInfo = TraceFieldEnum.Data | TraceFieldEnum.Headers | TraceFieldEnum.Cookies);
I will change it to 0 and see. Does this means the command is executed just once and does not re-try? What other implications does this change affects? Just to be cautious

Comment: The only thing I can see possibly happening is that the task creation fails for some reason without the retry.  This would be very interesting to dig into though, to see what the underlying failure is...

Comment: Kyle, I updated the retries to 0 in the code. See below:   

RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(null, RallyRestApi.DEFAULT_WSAPI_VERSION, 0, RallyRestApi.DEFAULT_TRACE_FIELDS); instead of
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi();
But I still see the error. The issue is the task creation is successful, but the API is recreating the second time instead of exiting out of the call. I believe there is some logic inside the API method that is broken where it iterates second time within the rest API code.  This is a recent occurrence about last 2-3  weeks. Any thoughts?
Thanks